# how build angular 2 with separated output files?

Tags: angular

I have 4 angular apps that use same libraries ( like angular , angular-material ... ).

I'm trying to get libraries in on file and my codes in another file so then I can use same library for all 4 apps(client don't have to load same library in 4 different app).

**update**

I want to share a single js file for all my app that client uses for which I want to use same URL for js file in all Apps so browser will automatically use cached js file instead of loading file each time, that's why I'm trying to have build structure like this :

- lib.js include all libraries like angular , angular-material and ... ( I will use this one as shared library js file in all apps )
- my.js  it's include code written by myself for each app ( in this case I will have 4 different my.js file for different apps)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question bit more?

Comment: @RukshanDangalla , question updated

Comment: Why do you want to work with js files ? Angular handle them for you , you can use just separated modules ( material module and etc ) in you'r project

Comment: and That is not a good practice my friend , It's better to import required libraries for each app individually.

Comment: Exactly, you can make your life more easier by using ES5/6 modules. And the other hand if you use node, it will take care all the dependencies for you :)

Comment: I already did that. I have sharedModule for all kind of components i use in my app and then I pack them as a package and use them inside my apps. but problem is I have a copy In each one of my apps and I don't want to do that because client should load about 1200KB library for each app. If I can have this library in a separate file I can use it as a shared library in all apps , that's what I'm asking for.

Comment: @RukshanDangalla I'm agree with you , Whatever molikh is asking is possible but **IT IS NOT BEST PRACTICE**

Comment: how can I do that? any tips will be helpful.

Comment: problem comes up when I should use this library in a company that have about 20 apps for their clients and this means client should load one library 20 times ( about 24MB) and it's not good at all !!

Comment: @molikh Can't you create you own npm package and share it among the apps? Also if you want to cache the packages, you can go for service worker kind of approach

Comment: I already packed my components and I share them that way. service worker works only for one app and doesn't help me in this issue.